# Regex to find strings that start and end with letter

Tags: java, regex

I need to write a regex that checks if:

- string starts and end with letter
- contains only letters, numbers, _ and ,
- _ can be present only between 2 letters, 2 numbers or a letter and a number
- , can be present only between 2 letters

What i have until now is this: `^[a-zA-Z][(a-zA-Z0-9_)(,a-zA-Z0-9_)]*[a-zA-Z]$`,  but I don't know how to add the last 2 requirements to it.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a case insensitive match, you could use

```
^[a-z][a-z0-9]*(?:_[a-z0-9]+)*(?:(?<![0-9]),[a-z][a-z0-9]*(?:_[a-z0-9]+)*)*$(?<![0-9])
```

- `^` Start of string
- `[a-z][a-z0-9]*` Match a single a-z and optional a-z0-9
- `(?:_[a-z0-9]+)*` Optionally repeat `_` and a-z0-9
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `(?<![0-9]),[a-z][a-z0-9]*(?:_[a-z0-9]+)*` Repeat the previous pattern asserting not 0-9 before the comma
- `)*` Close group and optionally repeat
- `$(?<![0-9])` End of string, assert not ending on a digit

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gQWu2A/1)

Comment: thank you, but its not working properly on cases like "word1_2_word" or "word_2k"

Comment: @SarateanTimeea Ah, like this then `^[a-z][a-z0-9]*(?:_[a-z0-9]+)*(?:(?<![0-9]),[a-z][a-z0-9]*(?:_[a-z0-9]+)*)*$
` https://regex101.com/r/f12oDm/1/

Comment: one thing though, it cannot end with digit

Comment: @SarateanTimeea You can account for that with a lookbehind `^[a-z][a-z0-9]*(?:_[a-z0-9]+)*(?:(?<![0-9]),[a-z][a-z0-9]*(?:_[a-z0-9]+)*)*$(?<![0-9])` https://regex101.com/r/gQWu2A/1, or shorter `^[a-z][a-z\d]*(?:_[a-z\d]+)*(?:(?<!\d),[a-z][a-z\d]*(?:_[a-z\d]+)*)*$(?<!\d)`